# Using Map/Dictionary as an alternative to switch case

Tags: java, dictionary, switch-statement, java-stream, language-agnostic

At the risk of this being an opinion based question, would creating a Map/dictionary where the keys are predicates and the values the action to be made be a good and viable substitute for switch case?

For example (following Java Map) :

```
    Map.of(predicate1, action1, ... predicateN, actionN)
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey()).findAny()
    .ifPresentOrElseThrow().getValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting approach, I sometimes do it for filters or mappers. The only thing I would change would be to avoid using a `Map` if you don't really need one (what would be the hashcode of your Predicate - it can be looked up, but still, it's not super straightforward).

Instead, you can put the Predicate and the Consumer in some sort of `Pair<>` or `Tuple<>`, or even create your own structure:

```
record PossibleAction<T>(
        Predicate<T> predicate,
        Consumer<T> action
) {
    // if you use a custom structure you can define these methods
    // and use .appliesFor(data) instead of using .getPredicate().test(data)
    public boolean appliesFor(T data) {
        return predicate.test(data);
    }

    public void apply(T data) {
        action.accept(data);
    }
}
```

Now you can have a list of these `PossibleActions`:

```
List<PossibleAction<String>> actions = List.of(
    new PossibleAction<>(s -> s.contains("A"), s -> System.out.println("1") ),
    new PossibleAction<>(s -> s.contains("B"), s -> System.out.println("2") ),
    new PossibleAction<>(s -> s.contains("C"), s -> System.out.println("3") )
);
```

And you can use this, as pointed out by you in the initial post:

```
void performActions(String data) {
    actions.stream()
            .filter(a -> a.appliesFor(data))
            .forEach(a -> a.apply(data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what's the problem of the predicate's hashcode?

Comment: I'd also point out that your approach in the last described function is mutative, which isn't the expected thing to do when filtering.

Comment: Of course, it was just an example, you can use a Function instead of the Consumer

Comment: You still didn't explain what you meant by the problem of the predicate's hashcode!

Comment: I didn't say there's a problem, but it can be hard/tricky to know how they are calculated. For an object, it can be calculated based on its fields, but for a function, it can be harder to determine it. Moreover, whenever have a `Map` but we only use its `entrySet()`, it might be a sign that there can be a more appropriate data structure for it.

Comment: That was in essence my question; does the `Map -> entrySet()` with the predicates as keys make sense. What other data structure did you have in mind?

Comment: I believe a `List<Pair<Predicate, Consumer>>` would make more sense. It's basically what I wrote in my answer

Comment: I'd say there is also a significant difference if the map is evaluated lazily or not and whether it is done in parallel. if it is done in parallel obviously the predicates must not cause side effects, whereas a classic if-else or switch statement can change state and are evaluated sequentially

Comment: addressing your concern in an earlier comment about calculating a hashcode for a function, after studying a bit of Clojure it seems that at least there each anonymous function is unique even if the code is the same because it uses the refrences to the functions created. Now this may case headaches if you're manipulating the map, but as in this case the keys are declared once and are just really using the map as a convenience, it doesn't matter much.